# array_keys or in_array insensitive doesnt work correctly

Tags: php, arrays, case-insensitive, array-key

i have a problem with insensitive array_keys and in_array ...
I developing a translator, and i have something like this:

```
$wordsExample = array("example1","example2","example3","August","example4");
$translateExample = array("ejemplo1","ejemplo2","ejemplo3","Agosto","ejemplo4");


function foo($string,$strict=FALSE)
{
    $key = array_keys($wordsExample,$string,$strict);
    if(!empty($key))
      return $translateExample[$key[0]];
    return false;
}

echo foo('example1'); // works, prints "ejemplo1"
echo foo('august');  // doesnt works, prints FALSE
```

I tested with in_array and same result...:

```
function foo($string,$strict=FALSE)
{
    if(in_array($string,$wordsExample,$strict))
      return "WOHOOOOO";
    return false;
}

echo foo('example1'); //works , prints "WOHOOOOO"
echo foo('august'); //doesnt works, prints FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the array and find the keys with with [`strtolower`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php):

```
$wordsExample = array("example1","example2","example3","August","example4");
$lowercaseWordsExample = array();
foreach ($wordsExample as $val) {
    $lowercaseWordsExample[] = strtolower($val);
}

if(in_array(strtolower('august'),$lowercaseWordsExample,FALSE))
      return "WOHOOOOO";

if(in_array(strtolower('aUguSt'),$lowercaseWordsExample,FALSE))
      return "WOHOOOOO";
```

Another way would be to write a new `in_array` function that would be case insensitive:

```
function in_arrayi($needle, $haystack) {
    return in_array(strtolower($needle), array_map('strtolower', $haystack));
}
```

If you want it to use less memory, better create the words array using lowercase letter.

Comment: Yes, is one way to do it, but system can be use many memory if you have many translations to do

Comment: You don't need to create two arrays, create just the one but create it using lowercase letter. That way you won't have to create another instance

Comment: consider using array_map() to lowercase the array entries

Answer (score 0):

I created a small function a while to get, to test clean-URLs as they could be uppercase, lowercase or mixed:

```
function in_arrayi($needle, array $haystack) {

    return in_array(strtolower($needle), array_map('strtolower', $haystack));

}
```

Pretty easy this way.